# Could not access the UIComponent value outside ValueChangeListener

Tags: java, runtime, oracle-adf, valuechangelistener

In many situation I need to use the value of some `UIComponent` during run-time in many places in the application. But the problem is I could not access the component's value outside its`ValueChangeListener`. I tried to store this value in local temporary variable, I also tried to use the `Binding` propriety but it did not work out.

This thread: [Changes done in the ValueChangeListener is not reflecting else where](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2616959)

tells that I should proceed everything in the `ValueChangeListener` but this is not useful in my case and it is really limiting my choices later.

So, Question is: **How to access the component value outside ValueChangeListener ?**

I am using `Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3 with ADF technology`

Comment: There is no single method that can get value(s) selected for all the UIComponents. It depends on the component. Which one(s) in particular are you wondering? I can give you examples then. Af:InputText? AF:selectmanychoice? Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this method: I create an instance variable of the component type. I set its value within the ValueChangeListener from the original component. Then I am able to use it within that bean. But you should be careful to beans scope. Try it with a session bean scope. If it is fine, then you should reconsider your bean scopes ;)

Comment: It was all about the bean scope. I changed the scope for the bean to be session scope and both my and yours methods worked out.